# .bash_profile wont run on login

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile, xmodmap

I am trying to set up my computer so that the escape key performs the caps lock function and caps lock performs the escape key function. I have a small script to swap my escape and caps lock using xmodmap.  In my .bash_profile, which is in my home directory, I put this line:

```
xmodmap ~/.capsswap
```

which to my knowledge, should run .capsswap, which I have in my home directory as well, when I log in.

the contents of .capsswap are

```
  1 ! Swap caps and Escape
  2 
  3 remove Lock = Caps_Lock
  4 keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
  5 keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
  6 add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Basically this isn't working as nothing happens on when I log in.  I'm pretty new to using bash and xmodmap in general, and I could be totally wrong with what I am doing, so if anyone knows how to fix this problem, or can suggest a better way to swap the escape and caps lock, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `~/.capsswap` to `~/.Xmodmap`

`~/.Xmodmap` is read by `/etc/gdm/Xsession`.

If you're not using gdm, you could add a script named: `91xmodmap`

in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`

that contains:

```
XMODMAP="$(which xmodmap)"
SYSMODMAP="/etc/X11/Xmodmap"
USRMODMAP="$HOME/.Xmodmap"
if [ -x $XMODMAP ]; then
    if [ -f "$SYSMODMAP" ]; then
        $XMODMAP "$SYSMODMAP"
    fi
    if [ -f "$USRMODMAP" ]; then
        $XMODMAP "$USRMODMAP"
    fi
fi
```

The command you put in your `~/.bash_profile` isn't running because gnome-terminal doesn't run as a login shell by default.

Right click on gnome-terminal's screen and go to `Profiles -> Profile Preferences`.

Then under the `Title and Command`, check `Run command as a login shell`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a GUI for changing the CapsLock behavior

Open `Keyboard Layout` settings and click `Options`.  You can select the `Caps Lock key behavior` in there.